# How to execute test cases after ide crashed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, testng, cucumber, junit

Kindly suggest if I have 100 test cases after executing 40 Test Cases  my IDE was crashed. So, on the next time when I am restarting my Test Cases again the execution should be start from 41 to 100.
I need to understand the above scenario in both TestNg and Cucumber-Junit

If we are executing the test cases in 3 browser then how many report will be created. in terms of both type of framework TestNg & Cucumber Junit

Comment: What's the reason for your IDE to crash?

Comment: I don't understand but somehow it was stopped working then it got crashed.

Comment: Does it work when you run from a terminal? It maybe a memory leak from your IDE.

Comment: which IDE are you using , update the IDE . Test automation is not IDE depended. it is just for easy script development. So this is not a real life use case. If you are doing this in your project you should start running test from cmd and not IDE

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen ok will update the same thanks for helping me